# Find the next number in order

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

Find the next number in the sequence
9, 73, 241, 561, 1081, 1849,____

Comment: This isn't really a puzzle, and the hint makes its 'solution' no more than a mechanical process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> $2913 = 14^3 + 13^2$

Reasoning

> The $n$th term in the sequence is given by the formula $$ a_n = 8n^3 + 4n^2 - 4n + 1 = (2n)^3 + (2n-1)^2 $$ i.e, the cube of the $n$th even number plus the square of the $n$th odd number.

First differences

> 64, 168, 320, 520, 768,...

Second differences

> 104, 152, 200, 248,...

Third differences

> 48, 48, 48,...

Consequence

> Since the third differences appear to be constant (at least the first three given), this means that the sequence will satisfy a cubic polynomial in the positive integers. In this case, it turns out the coefficients are integers so this is probably the right answer.

Comment: So, this just happened to be a simple interpolation polynomial (which is the easiest way to interpolate).